# Android: Animated gif

Tags: android

I've got an animated gif which is a loading bar. The image displays but there is no animation, how would I get it to animate?

Comment: How are you setting the image? Is it ImageView or background?

Answer (score 2):

ImageView cannot display animated gifs directly. You have to decompose the animated gif into frames (separate gif files) and animate them using an AnimationDrawable.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: not so true that "it can't".. you can use **decodeStream** method of **Movie** class. There is relatively good example here: http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/ ;)